# Cross-software text description/definition of a presets and styles?

Tags: style, presets

Is there a human-readable, textual format that describes changes (style/presets) that you can apply on the image? Then this format can be read in multiple photo editing softwares and easily shared by ppl.

### Example

This is a trivial example, but you will get the picture ;)

```
Name: MyCoolContrastOnBlue
Contrast: +15            <- increase of the contrast
Hist.blue: (0.7, 0.7)    <- added a point in histogram
Brightness: -2
Saturation: -32.1
Noise: -2
```

and so on. Then we can share sets of presets/styles, and make an open community of it.

Of course, some algorithms depend on software (like noise reduction, blur), but we can add modifiers like:

```
Noise: -2
Noise<CaptureOne.9>: -2.1
```

So if the software is CaptureOne, we actually use `-2.1` noise reduction etc.

Is there something like this in this world?

Comment: What is `Hist.blue: (0.7, 0.7)` supposed to do?

Comment: @mattdm if we imagine histogram as axes, from 0-1, and by default we have two points in (0,0) and (1,1) - then every new dot will be added with its coordinates, and the line gets interpolated through these dots. So in this case, curve goes from 0,0 -> 0.7,0.7 -> 1,1

Comment: Ahhh. Generally in photography software, we'd call that a _curves_ adjustment. You can think of a histogram as underlying the curves tool, but it's maybe better thought of as a representation of its _result_.

Comment: True, this was just a quick-and-dirty example, my bad. Thanx @mattdm.

Comment: Yeah, I did get the basic point. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is currently no such standard. The closest thing is Lightroom sidecar XMP files as a defacto standard. These aren't exactly human-readable (because they're XML rather than the simple key-value format you propose), but at least they're text. And they're not standardized, but some other programs (like Darktable) can at least attempt to interpret them.

For example, Darktable [says](https://www.darktable.org/2013/02/importing-lightroom-development/) that crop, rotation, flip, and tags can be understood completely; while exposure, some aspects of the tone curve, local contrast, and a few other things can be at least attempted, but aren't accurate.

Comment: Maybe we can work on making this standardized? wdyt @mattdm?

Comment: Standards are hard. In order to be really meaningful, you'd have to convince 800lb gorilla Adobe. But, you could start with Rawtherapee, Darktable, Lightzone, Ufraw, and other open source converters, and then maybe convince some of the more niche proprietary players to join in.

Comment: I didn't ask this because it is easy :))) And even gorillas like small bananas! Anyway, i find this cool., but maybe Im wrong, so would like to see what community thinks.

Comment: and this can start in baby (gorilla) steps, that is the nice part.

Comment: In general with an idea like this, *thinking of it* is cheap — ***code*** does the real convincing.

Comment: Hm, to get there you need to think; anyway; i am not getting the real answer - would it be worth it? But ok, maybe this is not the subject of the question anymore. Thanx @mattdm

Comment: Would it be worth it? It'd be pretty great for consumers to be able to move RAW images plus conversion instructions from program to program. But what value are you using to judge "worth it"?

Comment: Exactly that one you mentioned, the users value, exactly how you said it: RAW+conversion to be software-agnostic. Thanx!